# Why does my website menu move around in Internet Explorer only?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, menubar

I programmed a website with a fixed menu on the top, but in the Internet Explorer 11 it moves around for half a second or something like that when I click a button in the menu. In other browsers it works fine. What can I change to remove the bug, I think it has to do with my CSS code.

It would be very nice if someone could help me.
I want the buttons to be the same in IE and Mozilla, Chrome. I think that the IE is always a bit different to the other browsers.

Here is my CSS code for the Navigation menu:

```
    /* CSS Menu Navigation Bar */

    #cssmenu

    {   
       position: relative;  
       margin: 0 auto;
       clear: both; 
    }

    #cssmenu a 
    {       
       list-style: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       border: 0;
       line-height: 1.5; 
    }

    #cssmenu li 
    {   
       border: 1px solid transparent;
       padding-top: 7px;
       display: block; 
       float: right; 
       margin: 0 10px;
    }

    #cssmenu ul
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: -70px;
        max-height: 80px;
    }

    #cssmenu li a 
    {  
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;   
        width: 70px;
 
        border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
        text-decoration: none;  
        display: block;
    
        border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 2px;      
   
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;
        color: #292F33;
   }

   #cssmenu li:hover a 
   {  
        border-bottom: 3px solid #30B0FF;   
        display: block;
        color: #30B0FF;
        clear: both;

        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;

        transition-duration: 0.05s;
        transition-delay: 0.03s;
   }

  /* screen smaller than 1325px */

  @media only screen and (max-width : 1325px),
  only screen and (max-device-width : 1325px)
  {
       #menu
       {
          min-width: 1020px;
       }

       #cssmenu li a 
       {        
          padding-top: 10px;
          padding-right: 0px;
          padding-left: 0px;
          padding-bottom: 10px; 

          width: 60px;      
          font-size: 15px;
          border: 1px solid transparent;

       }

       #cssmenu li:hover a 
       {        
          font-size: 15px;  
       }
  }
```

And here is the important HTML code:

```
<!-- Menu -->       

    <div id="menu">     
        
        <li style="list-style: none;"> <img id="image" src="images/head.png"/><br><i>&nbsp;{by Ivan Ilic}</i></li>
        
        <div id='cssmenu'>      
        
            <ul>                                        

                <li><a href='lazarus.html'>Lazarus</a></li> 
                <li><a href='scratch.html'>Scratch</a></li>
                <li><a href='html.html'>HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href='c-sharp.html'>C#</a></li>
                <li><a href='c++.html'>C++</a></li>
                <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>                  
                                
            </ul>       

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I checked it in IE9, and used the dev tools to check 7 and 8 and quirks mode, it didn't move at all for me.

Comment: Which IE are you talking about? I've tested in IE9, IE10, and IE11, and I can't reproduce the error in any of those. Is this a problem with 7-8, or with 6?

Comment: the problem appears in IE 11

Comment: it is not the same in Mozilla, Chrome, ...

Comment: the buttons refresh themselves and it looks like they disappear and then after some miliseconds they appear again...

Comment: I would want them to stay fixed like in the other browsers :)

Comment: Are you referring to the `active` styles?  The only flash I see is when you click, and if you click and hold you can see the styles that would make it appear to flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "flash" you're seeing is the default `active` background color.  When you click, it flashes gray, which gives the appearance of movement.  You need to have a [CSS Style Reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) to override the default background color in IE.  Alternatively, you can simply change the active style itself.

Example:

```
:active { background:transparent; }
```

The [style reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) will prevent most cross-browser styling differences by overriding all the different default styles that browsers tack on.  I tested this with F12 Developer Tools and it eliminated the flash.

**Edit:**

The use of `document.write()` to add the style sheet is slowing down in IE.  Essentially the content is being painted, and then "fixed" once the styles are loaded.  Link the style sheet without JS and the flash will disappear.

Comment: it doesn't remove the bug, i think. Try pressing F5. The buttons refresh/the positions of the buttons refresh. They move away and come back after some miliseconds... And in all the other browsers they don't.

Comment: Mind trying something for me?  Rather than `document.write` the CSS in, just link it.

Comment: I think loading the styles with `document.write()` is causing the flash.  Can you test that?  Still seeing the CSS loaded via javascript on your page.

Comment: ups, oh yes now I see... You are right. It worked. Thanks :) But I used the document.write to load up the right css file (if mobile device or not) How can I do it now?

Comment: I'll add that to the answer so that it accurately reflects the correct answer.